# Order in size for fixture drains to enter the main stack

Tags: plumbing, drain

I am adding drains for a first floor bath and have replaced the main stack and vent.  In what order should I connect the drains into the stack?  Should a 1.5" sink drain enter the stack above or below the 3" closet bend?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your stack is coming off of the sink or the water closet. Does this help?
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the schematic.  However, I am in the basement with the question of which (height) order to introduce the basin and toilet into the soil stack.  No wet vent involved.  Each can be drained in independently.